# Notification on comment email

Tags: comments

I have on my site "Notification on comment" 
How can I disable notifications in a case that I post to myself?

Thanks
Tzvika

Comment: How have you provide this ability? are you using a module for that like Comment Notify or have you provided that using rules?

Comment: I am not sure it's just there i guess , i am new to durpal . if i go to the configuration -> people i have the ability to  add to select notification comment

Comment: Which drupal module is this question about? Is it https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify ? If not where can I find that module?